# Help, ubuntu server 14.04 crontab cannot run my database backup script, but other simple script is ok

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, cron

Hi All Ubuntu Server Experts

I need help in cracking this crontab problem.
So, I made a change in /etc/crontab to run a system script for database backup purpose. The crontab does not seems to run my script and I cannot view the crontab status anywhere. I even uses root account for my ubuntu server.

So, I made a simple echo script in crontab and it worked ok. What is wrong with my script?

Here are some clues:
This is my /etc/crontab file

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/DataBank/Bac$

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
*  *    * * *   root    sh /DataBank/Backup/Scripts/backupdb.sh --> this one does not run
*  *    * * *   root    echo "Running Sample Crontab by the minute: $(date)" >>$ --> this one works
```

and This is my backup scripts located at /DataBank/Backup/Scripts/backupdb.sh:

```
echo "Backing up database... $(date)" >> backuplog.txt
DBFILENAME=db`date "+%Y%m%d-%H.%M.%S"`.sql
/Tech/MySQL/Server/bin/mysqldump -c ITWorksEEDB > ../DB/$DBFILENAME --user=root$
echo "Backup done: $DBFILENAME $(date)" >> backuplog.txt
```

and My backup file permissions: (all 777)

```
root@MoMa:/DataBank/Backup/Scripts# ls -al
total 11
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jan  4 13:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Oct  8 21:13 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  257 Jan  4 13:05 backupdb.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  257 Jan  4 13:32 backupdb.sh.bak
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  236 Jan  4 13:05 backuplog.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   79 Jun 25  2013 shutAll.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   55 Aug 23  2012 shutSPC.sh
```

When I run the backupdb.sh manually using "sh backupdb.sh", it works perfectly.
When I use this command: ./backupdb.sh (without sh), this error message occurs:

```
root@MoMa:/DataBank/Backup/Scripts# ./backupdb.sh
-bash: ./backupdb.sh: Permission denied --> My backupdb.sh file is supposed to be 777
```

Can anyone help me how to make the script run in crontab or at least to see the status returned by crontab when running the script?

Thank you
Rendra

Comment: Two things, 1) **never edit crontab manually**, always use `crontab -e` from the specific user account. 2) **cron has no environment**, i.e. just because a command in on your `PATH` does not mean that it will be on cron's.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question... It is simple actually after trial and error... the script to be set in crontab MUST contain FULL PATH, not relative path.

I hope my experience can help anyone out there since crontab does not provide any analysis of what happened when a script does not run.

Comment: Crontab emails the user running the command with the output in case of error.